# How to add and access Custom Header in C#

Tags: http, header

I need to add a custom header something like
MYName: Balaji
which i need to access from .aspx file through
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_MYName"];
should return "Balaji". I need so many variables like this it will added dynamically.
Kindly help.

Also, I cannot persist this varaibles in any of the .Net controls or objects like 
cookies, sessions, application, hidden variable etc., or cannot store this in d/b and get it back whenever is required, I NEED IT ONLY IN HTTP HEADERS.

Kindly send the C# code how to add this variable and get the value back in .aspx file.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "get the value back in .aspx file"? HTTP headers are intended to be used as directives to a browser, how to interpret the given content. You don't have access to these values in your document.

Setting a custom HTTP header is quite easy, however:

```
   Page.Response.AddHeader("MyCustomHeader", "VerySecretValue")
```

---

**Updated** my answer as per your comment. 
If you need to transfer information between a HTTPModule and an ASPX page, you can use `HTTPContext.Current`, since this stays the same in both places.
So, you add it by

```
  HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("SecretKey", "SecretValue");
```

and read it as

```
  string s = HttpContext.Current.Items["SecretKey"];
```

Comment: Ok, got your point. Is it possible to set the value somewhere (either in httpmodule or httphandler) and get it back through Request.ServerVariables["<MyKey>"]